# DOM keeps being rebuilding with angular-selectize ng-repeat and track by

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-track-by

I'm using AngularJS with the [angular-selectize](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize) module.

To populate the page with the elements I need I use something like this:

#### index.html

```
<selectize
    ng-repeat="select in selects_data track by $index"
    config="selectizeConfig"
    options="select.options"
    ng-model="selects_models[select.name]">
</selectize>
```

#### controller.js

```
$scope.update_data = function(){
    //I'm using AngularJS resource to get the JSON data from the server
    $scope.selects_data = StatesTableControl.get({'path': $scope.element.path},
        function(data){
            //Success
            angular.forEach(data, function(item){
                $scope.selects_models[item.name] = item.current_id
            });
        }, function(error){
            //Error
        }
    );
};

$scope.update_data();
$interval($scope.update_data, 3000);
```

No matter whether I use `track by $index`, `track by select.name` or don't use it at all, all of the `<selectize></selectize>` elements are redrawing completely every time I update the `selects_data` array with the data obtained from the server, even if the array content is the same after updating.

I haven't found any recipe to solve it by myself.
And I can't understand why `track by` helps with the same thing when I use it inside `div` or other elements.

I'll be really glad if someone can help with the issue!

Comment: Could you paste the code responsible for updating the `selects_data`?

Comment: @ConstantinePoltyrev I expanded the code example in my question, I hope it will help to clarify what's going on in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with the way you track items. If `StatesTableControl.get` returns new objects everytime you call it, I think angular considers they're different objects, even if they contain the same data.

You could send only the objects that have changed, or maintain a version number for the objects so you know the ones that haven't changed and you don't replace them.

Comment: Thank for the reply.
When I use 'ng-repeat' without the 'track by' option, DOM elements rebuilds every time the source object or array changes.
But if I use 'track by $index' option, DOM changes only when new elements appears or old elements are gone. 
It works with oher html elements like '<div>' but it doesn't work with the '<selectize>' elements. I just don't get why.